# How to disable enter press in <Select> field?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I have this element:

```
<Select>
  <Option value='1'>1</Option>
  <Option value='2'>2</Option>
</Select>
```

I want to disable form submission when Enter is pressed. I tried the following with `<Input>` field:

```
<Input onPressEnter={disableEventHelper} />

disableEventHelper = (e) => e.preventDefault();
```

But, for some reason, this didn't work for `<Select>`
Is there is another way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `onKeyDown`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try code snippet in your Javascript code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

**However**, if you only want to target your form, then do the following:

Say your form has a class called `your-form`:

```
const form = document.querySelector('.your-form');

form.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This completely disables the Enter key on the entire page.